# Experiences with Busman DR-680

Tags: field-recording, field-recorder, tascam-dr-680

Anyone care to share any experiences or reviews of the Busman modded DR-680? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I bought one. Guess I'll find out on monday how good it sounds.